# Angular 8: markAsTouched is not trigger the errors I define for controls of form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a weird problem in angular 8. 
I have a parent component and a child component.
I used reactive forms in child component and access this form in parent component via ViewChild.
this ViewChild is static: false.
I call markAsTouched for each control of this form in parent component in submit button but this will not show the errors I defined for controls.
I have several pages like this.
some of them fully functional.
some of them half functional.
but this one is not functional about showing form errors.
It was working fine before but suddenly we faced this problem.
anyone here can help me?
I stuck in this problem a few days.

Comment: Try triggering change detection for the child component

Comment: Could your provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @DPro
thank you. you gave me an idea to resolve my problem.

Comment: provide a minimal example of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I moved all assignments for my form to child component. 
also I used changeDecector.detectChanges() when I wanted to show the errors. 
that's all. this resolved my problem.